# separate controller logic and factory logic in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, factory

I don't want to have all my code in one huge controller, so I'm trying to restructure it a little bit, but I'm running into this error

```
Argument 'protocolController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I have my factory

```
/*
    FACTORY THAT HANDLES ALL REQUESTS.
*/

function asyncFactory() {

    var factory = this;

    factory.list = [];

    this.update = function(restUrl) {
        return $http.get(restUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            factory.list = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };

    this.add = function(formData, restUrl){
        $http.post(restUrl, JSON.stringify(formData))
        .success(function(data){
            console.log('Success: ' + data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };

    this.remove = function(value, restUrl){
        // get index of clicked object
        var index = this.protocolList.indexOf(value);

        // Remove object with given index from array
        factory.list.splice(index, 1);

        var url = restUrl + value.id;

        // delete it from DB
        $http['delete'](url);

        console.log('Deleted object with ID ' + value.id);
    };

    // Change existing object
    this.change = function(value, restUrl) {

        // get index of clicked object
        var index = this.protocolList.indexOf(this.activeObject);

        var url = restURL + value.id + '/' + value.name;
        console.log('url: ' + url)
        // change it before store it to DB
        $http['put'](url);

        console.log('Changed object with ID ' + this.activeObject.id);

    };
}
```

and my controlller that utilizes the factory

```
/*
    PROTOCOL CONTROLLER
*/
function protocolController(asyncFactory){

    var controller = this;
    controller.list = asyncFactory.list;
    controller.formData = {};

    this.getUpdatedList = function() {
        asyncFactory.update('../protocols')
        .then(function(data){
            controller.list = data;
        });
    };

    this.addData = function(formData){
        asyncFactory.add(formData, '../protocols');
    };

    this.removeData = function(value){
        asyncFactory.remove(value, '../protocols');
    };

    this.editData = function(value){
        asyncFactory.change(value, '../protocols')
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
/*
    MAIN - WHERE THE CONTROLLER AND FACTORY IS CALLED
*/
var app = angular.module('TransactionMonitoring', [])
.controller('protocolController', protocolController(asyncFactory));
```

Comment: Your factory looks more like a service to me (factories get called and return something. Services are instantiated using new). I also recommend reading [John Papas styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and to adopt some of that into your code (Dependency injection using array syntax, named functions instead of anonymous, getter/setter syntax instead of var app...)

Comment: I updated your code according to what I would have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change :**

/*
    MAIN - WHERE THE CONTROLLER AND FACTORY IS CALLED
*/

```
var app = angular.module('TransactionMonitoring', [])
.controller('protocolController', protocolController(asyncFactory));
```

**To,**

/*
    MAIN - WHERE THE CONTROLLER AND FACTORY IS CALLED
*/

```
var app = angular.module('TransactionMonitoring', [])
.controller('protocolController', function(asyncFactory){

  var controller = this;
    controller.list = asyncFactory.list;
    controller.formData = {};

    this.getUpdatedList = function() {
        asyncFactory.update('../protocols')
        .then(function(data){
            controller.list = data;
        });
    };

    this.addData = function(formData){
        asyncFactory.add(formData, '../protocols');
    };

    this.removeData = function(value){
        asyncFactory.remove(value, '../protocols');
    };

    this.editData = function(value){
        asyncFactory.change(value, '../protocols')
    }
}


});
```

SERVICE:

```
app.service('asyncFactory',function ($http) {
 this.update = function(restUrl) {
        return $http.get(restUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            factory.list = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };

    this.add = function(formData, restUrl){
        $http.post(restUrl, JSON.stringify(formData))
        .success(function(data){
            console.log('Success: ' + data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };

    this.remove = function(value, restUrl){
        // get index of clicked object
        var index = this.protocolList.indexOf(value);

        // Remove object with given index from array
        factory.list.splice(index, 1);

        var url = restUrl + value.id;

        // delete it from DB
        $http['delete'](url);

        console.log('Deleted object with ID ' + value.id);
    };

    // Change existing object
    this.change = function(value, restUrl) {

        // get index of clicked object
        var index = this.protocolList.indexOf(this.activeObject);

        var url = restURL + value.id + '/' + value.name;
        console.log('url: ' + url)
        // change it before store it to DB
        $http['put'](url);

        console.log('Changed object with ID ' + this.activeObject.id);

    };
}
}
)
```

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Consider explainign what you have changed and why, so that your answer is useful to learn what wen wrong.

Comment: @LionC If you're referring to my comment, I changed it exactly the way Ved suggested.

Comment: @Nilzone- No I was talking to Ved.

Comment: @LionC As you told that, factory more looks like service, I changed the code and updated my answer. The changes i have done are added '$http' as dependency in service.

Comment: I changed it, and now it works. Thank you :) But would you mind telling my why I can't do it the way I tried?

Comment: @Nilzone- I will surely look for this. And I will update you here with the mistakes. Currently the one mistake you are doing is not adding $http as dependency in your service.

Comment: ok - I'd appreciate it if you can just leave a comment here, or update your answer if you figure out what I did wrong, because I would actually prefere to write it that way.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through this.